# Map or Each for Values with Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to figure out the best way to update my underscore.js `.map` method since the inclusion of a new field value that should be grouped with the current value being passed to `.map`. Should I use `.map` or `.each` with the new update and should I store the values as an object or object in an array and pass that to the `.map` or `.each` to achieve my desired outcome? At the moment I tried the object approach with `.map`, but the values are coming through as arrays.

**Proper format:**

```
[ { reportTitle: 'Title1', reportLink: 'test.com', id: 166 },
  { reportTitle: 'Title2', reportLink: 'test2.com', id: 166 } ]
```

**Original (Working):**

```
var links = _.map(req.body.reportLink, function(link){
                    return {
                        reportLink: link,
                        id: blog.id
                    };
                });
```

**Output:**

```
[ { reportLink: 'test.com', id: 166 },
  { reportLink: 'test2.com', id: 166 } ]
```

**Updated (Not Working):**

```
var linkAttributes = { title: req.body.reportTitle, link: req.body.reportLink}
var links = _.map(linkAttributes, function(link) {
  return {
      reportTitle: link.title,
      reportLink: link.link,
      id: blog.id
  };
```

});

**Output:**

```
[ { reportTitle: [ 'Test 1', 'Test 2' ],
    reportLink: [ 'test1.com', 'test2.com' ],
    id: 164 } ]
```

Comment: Can you add an example of a input and the desired output?

Comment: @Phiter the "Proper format" is the desired outcome. Objects in an array that have the format of `{ reportTitle: *value*, reportLink: *value*, id: *value* }` This is present in the "Original" code, but since I added the `reportTitle` to the object and updated the map method I receive arrays for each iteration as the value of the property, rather than an object for each iteration.

Comment: Ok, and now the input as well please.

Comment: @HMR here are the formats `reportTitle (req.body.reportTitle): [ 'test-title', 'test-title2' ]` and `reportLink (req.body.reportLink):
[ 'test.com', 'test2.com' ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now clear what it is you're asking, the following should do the trick:

```js
const zip = (arr1, arr2) =>
  [...new Array(Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length))].map(
    (_, i) => [arr1[i], arr2[i]],
  );

const reportTitle = ['test-title', 'test-title2'];
const reportLink = ['test.com', 'test2.com'];
console.log(
  zip(reportTitle, reportLink).map(
    ([reportTitle, reportLink]) => ({
      reportTitle,
      reportLink,
      id: 166,
    }),
  ),
);
```

The zip utility takes 2 arrays (for example [1,2,3] and [5,6,7]) and returns an array with an element from each array: (`[[1,5],[2,6],[3,7]` from the example)

Then it [maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) over this array to create an array of objects.

The function passed to map uses [destructuring parameters](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#destructuring-parameters) to quickly name the 2 elements from the array passed to the map function.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the confusion. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`_.map` -> shoud have first argument as `array`

```
var linkAttributes = [
                       { 
                         title: req.body.reportTitle, 
                         link: req.body.reportLink
                        }
                     ]; // shoud be array
var links = _.map(linkAttributes, function(link) {
  return {
      reportTitle: link.title,
      reportLink: link.link,
      id: blog.id
  };
```

Comment: No [it does not](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#map)  `Arguments
collection (Array|Object): The collection to iterate over.`

Comment: @HMR for current situation we need to send array as first argument

Comment: You must be psychic to know current situation because the question is unclear what the input is. There is no need to pass array to `_.map` but you state: `Shold have first argument as array`, this is simply not true.